# How to add Widget to QTabWidget Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, qtabwidget

I have a Qt program which was made without Qt Creator. And I want to improve the functionality: put all that i have now (QGridLayout, QLabels, QPushButtons and QCustomPlot) in one tab of QTabWidget and make another one tab with another layout and widgets. How should i do it correctly? I tried to create QTabWidget and add to it my QGridLayout with all stuff. Mb it is right way.

Tried to find some info but all are using creator for their projects. i dont like it and so i cant find examples of how can i push all ready functionality to qtabwidget

This is my main function:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  Smartcalc calc;
  calc.resize(750, 500);
  calc.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

This is my constructor:

```
Smartcalc::Smartcalc(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
  createWidgets();
  initGraph(customPlot);
  mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
  addWidgetsToLayout(mainLayout);
  setWindowTitle(tr("Smartcalc_v1.0"));
  connectWidgets();
  customWidgets();
}
```

So i need to create two tabwidgets and push my Smartcalc functionality in one of tabwidgets.

Comment: You probably want to explain what part of the process of creating your QTabWidget caused you a problem. It's difficult to understand what type of help you need.

Comment: Unfortunately your edit doesn't really add any useful information.  If you want to add a widget to a `QTabWidget` as a new tab you call one of the [`QTabWidget::addTab`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtabwidget.html#addTab) overloads.  That's really all there is to it.

Comment: The code in the linked repository makes no mention of `QTabWidget`.  Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem(s) you're trying to solve.